# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /srv/disk7/1259829/www/k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/upload_file.php on line 102

Tags: php, string, image

I am using a HTML code to upload image into a "upload" folder thats the tutorial I used 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
I wanted to add extra functionality as I want to display iamges from that folder along with description so my plan is to store address to a file like http://k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/upload/$filename.$extension I am using mysql and I can connect to it
I have it working without putting data into database. (just uploading image to a folder)

thats the full php code
http: //justpaste.it/phpcodephpcode

and this is just my extra part

```
  <?php

$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="photo"; // Table name
  $imagestring = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
  $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (PhotoString) VALUES ("http://www.atspace.com/photoalbum/upload/'$imagestring'.'$filetype'")";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  ?>
```

I am getting this error:
http:// k00138899.atspace.eu/photoalbum/upload_file.php

Comment: look at the colours in the code above, should give you a hint. now start using a good IDE, that helps you with such 'trivial' errors. oh and never use w3schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change row

`$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (PhotoString) VALUES ("http://www.atspace.com/photoalbum/upload/'$imagestring'.'$filetype'")";`

for

`$sql='INSERT INTO '.$tbl_name.' (PhotoString) VALUES ("http://www.atspace.com/photoalbum/upload/'.$imagestring.'.'.$filetype.'")';`

Comment: You are simply the best better than all the rest ! Thank you very much so much to learn for me...

Comment: give a man a fish ...

Comment: :( @Dagon can you suggest a article explaining how to tackle this problems

Comment: learn the php syntax. any php intro starts with syntax. As i pointed uot above, using an 'intelligent' IDE would also be a great help.

Comment: You can't use same quotation marks in php and SQL because you finish string with " before link. Just use different quotation marks for SQL and php code.

Comment: Ok now I m better equipped thanks for giving me a hand here